# Real-time position of artificial satellites

Tags: data-request, geospatial, telecom, space

Is there a database containing the currently known course of most artificial satellites?

For instance, satellite X is travelling at speed n and at time T it will be at point P.

For all countries/owners.
Bonus if it includes space debris and natural objects that enter the vicinity of Earth.

If precise enough it could be used to prevent [collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_satellite_collision).

Comment: Just a start can be https://in-the-sky.org/satmap.php

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is ample data for you to play with.

stuffin.space uses a ridiculous amount of data from :

1. Satellite data - https://www.space-track.org/
2. Satellite.js - makes it easy to interpret velocity, and other SGP4/SDP4 calculations. (GITHUB - https://github.com/shashwatak/satellite-js)
3. A real-time interactive WebGL visualisation of objects in Earth orbit @ stuffin.space

Comment: SpaceTrack has an API. It publishes only part of the dataset for civvie users. You can also find a lot of data at Ted Molczan's satobs.org (SeeSat-L mailing list archives and other stuff).